# Which of the following signatures is realized by a nilpotent map on $\mathbb R ^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Which of the following signatures is realized by a nilpotent map on
>   $\mathbb R ^3$?
>
> (a) $(1,2,3)$
>
> (b) $(1,3)$
>
> (c) $(2,3)$

For this problem, I know that a signature $S$ is realized by a nilpotent map if there exists a nilpotent map $T$ on $V$ such that the signature of $F(T)$ which induced via kernel is equal to $S$.

If we use eigenvalues, a nilpotent map has all eigenvalues $0$, and signature may be induced. While is there any possible way that can solve this without using eigenvalue (i.e., from definition of nilpotent map signature)?

Comment: what is the signature of a nilpotent map?

Comment: the signature of a nilpotent map generally means $dim KerT^1, dim KerT^2...dim KerT^i$, here $KerT^i=\mathbb R ^3$.