# Which of the following signatures is realized by a nilpotent map on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Which of the following signatures is realized by a nilpotent map on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

```
(a)(1,2,3)
(b)(1,3)
(c)(2,3)
```

I found the duplicate question but it was not answered [Which of the following signatures is realized by a nilpotent map on $\mathbb R ^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293213/689675)

Comment: Well, a non-zero nilpotent linear map on $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ is of maximal nilpotency degree of $\;n-1\;$ , so if $\;n=3\;$ there aren't many options....

Comment: I think option(a) is incorrect and option(b) is correct but i am not sure about option(c). Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

What is the signature of the following nilpotent maps?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\;\;B=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

So what option cannot be?

Comment: rank of A = 1 and rank of B = 2. So option(c) cant be an answer. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, then you got $\;\dim\ker A=2\,,\,\,\dim\ker A^2=3\implies\;$(c) can be, and also $\;\dim\ker B=1,\,\,\dim\ker B^2=2\,,\,\,\dim\ker B^3=3\implies \;$ (a) can be...

Comment: I am more confused now :/

Comment: Then option(b) cant be correct by that logic

Comment: I think it is possible you're not seeing things the way I see them. For me, the signature of a nilpotent matrix $\;A\;$ being $\;(a,b,c,...)\;$ means that $\;\dim\ker A=a,\,\dim\ker A^2=b\;$ and etc. From this that it can't possibly be true that a nilpotent matrix has kernel with dimension $\;1\;$ and then the squared matrix has kernel with dimension 3 = the matrix is the zero matrix. Think of this. For me it is pretty easy using Jordan Canonical Form, but I think there must be some more basic ways to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

(a) and (c) are, but (b) is not.  For the former, let A:= $E_{12}+E_{23}$.  Then the linear maps induced by A and $A^2$ induce flags whose signatures are (a) and (b), respectively. To see that (b) cannot happen, suppose such a T existed for contra-diction. Note that Rank(T) = 2 and  that $T◦T = 0$ implies  that Im(T) ⊂ Ker(T).  So Nullity(T) ≥ 2.  This shows that dim $\mathbb{R}^3$ ≥ 2 + 2, which is a contradiction.